# Add prefix to words in a line with exception case

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to add a prefix to a list of relative path.
For example, if i have a variable, say, `t="Document .local/share Pictures/2019\ Mountains"`
I now want to edit it with awk or sed, in order to add "~/" before each word, so that it become `"~/Document ~/.local/share ~/Pictures/2019\ Mountains"`
How can I do that?
I was trying with `sed 's/[^ ]* */prefix-&/g'` but it add "~/" also between "2019" and "Mountains"

Comment: `before each word` - the `/` and \ and \+space are words delimeters. Before each word would be `~/Document ~/.local/~/share` etc. To handle \+space you have to write a parser. Are you expecting `"` and `'` quotes too? It would be way easier if you would obtain a newline/some custom character separated list of paths or a zero terminated list of  paths. Also, is this `ls` output?

Comment: Are you trying to write a script to change the code that initializes the variable `t` or the value of the variable `t` after it's been initialized by the code shown in your question or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "Document .local/share Pictures/2019\ Mountains" | 
  sed -r 's_^|([^\] )_\1~/_g'

~/Document ~/.local/share ~/Pictures/2019\ Mountains
```